# import problem loading plugins in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have been having troubles setting up plugins in javascript lately for some unknown reason no matter what i do it just doesn't work unless i use the following  format :

`import '../Prototype copy 7/node_modules/horizontal-scroll/dist/index.js';`

but I can't use this if I need to use multiple plugins at the same time i can't import at the same file, so i need to make separate js files...

any other format like the one below doesn't work

```js
import HorizontalScroll from '../Prototype copy 7/node_modules/horizontal-scroll/dist/index.js';
//
var blocks = document.getElementsByClassName('container__item');
var container = document.getElementsByClassName('container');
var hs = new HorizontalScroll.default({
    blocks: blocks,
    container: container,
    isAnimated: true,
    springEffect: 0.8,
});
```

I keep getting either
`Uncaught SyntaxError: import not found: default` or `Blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”)`

P.S. already have `type="module` in my html script tag...

any solution ...

Comment: What webserver back-end are you using,  Node / PHP / Apache etc.  As it sounds like it's sending Javascript files as HTML for it's mime type.

Comment: well I'm pretty much using node

Comment: @Namlind That doesn't help much; the question is trying to understand how your server is sending JS files, and what their mimetype is.

Comment: no idea about back-end I'm beginner ...